# page is not redirecting

Tags: url-rewriting

I want to redirect to a page to my home page if there would be found only one post.I have tried below code but it is
 not working, i have also tried header("location:url"), but it is also not working.

```
 <?php
       $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'posts_per_page'=> 10,
       'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
   $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
   $count=$my_query->found_posts; 
    if($count<2){
      wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect before any content is sent to the browser. If you had [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) enabled, you'd see errors about headers already being sent.

The question is light on detail but if there is a way to avoid the secondary loop and use the main query this should work (though I question the logic):

```
add_action(
  'template_redirect',
  function() {
    if (is_single()) {
      wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
      exit;
    }
  }
);
```

If you must have the secondary Loop, you need to run the query and make the decision about the redirect *before* `get_header` in your theme files.

Answer (score -1):

May be this will help you...

Try Following code :--

```
<?php
       $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'posts_per_page'=> 10,
       'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
   $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
   $count=$my_query->found_posts; 
    if($count<2){
      ob_clean();
      wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain ___why___ you think this might work? For my part, I don't see what adding `ob_clean()` is going to do to prevent a redirect error.