# Getting redirect to happen before header output

Tags: headers, plugin-gravity-forms, wp-redirect

Anyone know of a way to trick WordPress into doing a header location redirect. I have to check whether users are logged in or not, and if not redirect them to our organizations authorization system which is an external site.

I am getting output before my header() call, from WordPress outputting the queued scripts.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /.../wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php:128) in ...
```

I have a plugin, that had a class handler, that handles this with this method:

```
...
public function populateInfo($form) {
    $email = $this->hasEmail($form);
    /*$name = $this->hasName($form);
    $address = $this->hasAddress($form);
    $phone = $this->hasPhone($form);*/

    // let's get some auth info
    if($email !== false || $name !== false || $address !== false || $phone !== false) {
        $ldap = new LDAP();
        $webAuth = new Auth();
        $curPage = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $webAuth->url = $curPage;
        if($webAuth->isLoggedIn()) {
            $ldap->search($webAuth->getID());

            // set up form variables
            $form['fields'][$email['key']]['defaultValue'] = $ldap->getEmail();
        } else {
            // this is where redirect fails
            wp_redirect($webAuth->login_url);
            return;
        }
    }

    return $form;
}
...
```

### Update:

This method is called via a GravityForms filter:

```
add_filter('gform_pre_render', array($this, 'populateInfo'));
```

Which basically loads up info into a page form. The user must be logged in, in order for this form to populate (thus the `$webAuth->isLoggedIn()` check). Obviously I am aware that the headers are being output beforehand, my question is, how to properly workaround this in WordPress, so that I can redirect unauthorized users to the log in, without being brick-walled by preceding headers?

Comment: [There are numerous questions here about this issue already.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Cannot+modify+header+information)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've already dug through most of those, and they address the header issue, but don't address how to get the redirect to happen before headers are output. I know what that error means, I am in need of a solution. Can you show me which specific question of all of them would help me, please?

Comment: Please elaborate where and how the method is called.

Comment: I updated the question with more details.

Comment: @G896 Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Magne I did. I had to move the login check out of the `gform_pre_render` hook, and into another one called `gform_enqueue_scripts`, which occurs before the header output, therefore getting past my header output issue.

Answer (score 5):

Your method is called too late. I don't know how you call this method but you need to run it ***before*** output is sent to the browser-- usually that means before `get_header()`. There are a number of hooks that can be used. For example (from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131210/21376):

```
add_action(
  'template_redirect',
  function() {
    if (is_single()) {
      wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
      exit;
    }
  }
);
```

Without more context, it is impossible to say exactly what the right hook is.

Comment: I added more details in the question.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh : your edit doesn't change anything. You have to hook in before headers are sent. That isn't a WordPress limitation. It is a PHP/HTTP one.

Comment: Sorry! I can't get this answered elsewhere and being as it may that it involves WordPress and GravityForms hooks, this is the only venue, to which I can turn.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh : you have the information you need. You ___must___ hook in before headers are sent. I provided an example of how that can be done. (Apparently, the Gforms hook is too late.)

Comment: Yes, I have the info, but it's not helping. Any other ideas?

Comment: ... I could use `add_action(
  'template_redirect',
  function() {
    if (is_single()) {
      wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
      exit;
    }
  }
);` but I can't figure out how to get the $form object passed to it.

Comment: Gravity Forms is a commercial plugin and so is not specifically supported here. I don't know if Gravity Forms supports your use case. You may need to use the raw `$_POST` data.

Comment: Yes I know, we have a support license. They have yet to get back to me. I linked them to this Question, so hopefully they will get back to me sooner than later.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about Gravity Forms, but it's hard to believe there isn't an earlier hook you can use to put the redirect logic. It might force you to change some of the code, dig through source code, etc, but it's really a logic problem on your end.

Having said that, there is a workaround which I personally would advise you not to use, but it might work until you have more time to look into the problem. It's called output buffering: you basically ask PHP to hold onto the output until you tell it to 'release' it -- namely, after you've exhausted all possible redirections. [It has many caveats](http://pt1.php.net/ob_start), so be advised.

You might put something along these lines on your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action('init', 'my_prefix_start_buffer');
function my_prefix_start_buffer() {
    ob_start();
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'my_prefix_flush_buffer');
function my_prefix_flush_buffer() {
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

I'm assuming `gform_pre_render` is triggered after `init` and before `wp_footer`, but you might have to adjust accordingly.

With more info, we'd might be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that workaround, and it is dirty. Sadly that's not going to be an option. Yes, `gfrom_pre_render` is too late, unfortunately. More info? What exactly do you need to provide answer? I am limited by my organization's code sharing policies to offer up too much open code, so if you need specifics let me know what they are.

Comment: What is Gravity Forms hooking into? At which point is the `$form` object instantiated? Can't you hook there? Can't you make the object a global variable somehow? If you can't share code, or are unwilling to debug along with us, we can't help you. Personally, I don't appreciate a company unwilling to show its code coming here and asking for our help.

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue you are most likely encountering is not calling your function soon enough in the WP load process. This depends on what action hook you are using to call your function. See the [WordPress Action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for the appropriate order.

One other comment on your code, you should call `exit;` instead of `return;` after `wp_redirect();` as per the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

EDIT: To clarify the action reference stuff, the more context you can provide about when, where and how your function is called the more help everyone can be!

Comment: Please add this as an edit, as it is part of your answer :)

Comment: Okay. I get that. I already tried add_action('init'), which to me seems to be the correct one, but it didn't take. I have also used exit() and die() after the wp_redirect() call, and I am still getting the header modification error.

Comment: Okay, since you're getting info from the `gform_pre_render` function, you won't be able to change the action your function is called on unless you find another way to obtain that info. Ideally it would be no later than the `template_redirect` action, but as to how you would get your info, I am at a loss as I don't spend that much time with Gravity Forms.

Answer (score 0):

The correct hook to use is `template_redirect` which allows you to have the necessary info available to do checks while also early enough to actually redirect. As per the example on the codex page:

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
    {
    if( is_page( 'goodies' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/signup/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

Codex page here - [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)